# Connect a UITableViewCell to an Action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to use a specific cell with a disclosure indicator to bring up a `UIImagePicker` (the other cells have `UITextFields`, etc…) So far I have only been able to do it with a `UIButton`. I want to connect my action to the cell, but my only options are to create new segues. How would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: @LuisOscar , Please let me know how it gets increased? Even for me its too less.

Comment: I did not realize that it was appropriate to mark answers correct. Thanks (I marked the right answers on most of my questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index path of the cell you want to be tappable (its the first cell in the list or something). Then you could use:

```
-(void) tableview:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        // do some action
        [tableview deslectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self someAction];
    }
}
```

You are also going to want to set all the other cells in your cellForRowAtIndexPath to not respond to tap events.

Comment: How would I make other cells not respond to touch events? Also, my cell is the first one in the second section, so would the section == 1 and row == 0?

Comment: I know there is a way to disable touch events on a view, I don't know how to do that for cells though

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hardcode indexes for sections and rows, you can do something like this:

in .h file, create IBOutlets using IB

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *upgradeAppCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *spreadTheWordCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *rateOnAppStoreCell;
```

in .m file:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == upgradeAppCell)
    {
        [self upgradeApp];
    }
    else if (cell == spreadTheWordCell)
    {
        [self spreadTheWord];
    }
    else if (cell == rateOnAppStoreCell)
    {
        [self rateOnAppStore];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
   YourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
   if(!cell)
   {
       cell = /*Create your cell*/
       [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(didClickButton:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   }

   cell.button.tag = [indexPath row];   

   return cell;
}

-(void)didClickButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    int row = button.tag
    /*Here you'll be able to know the button of which row has been clicked.*/
}
```

Comment: I pretty much did the whole view in interface builder so I didn't want to complicate it by adding a cellForRowAtIndexPath method.